# How to use random with button in Kivy

Tags: kivy

I just want to have 2 buttons in my KIVY APP.

One with text "Hello" and other having a random number from 0-9.

My code

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from random import random

Builder.load_string("""
<Highest>:
    r1c1: "hello"
    r1c2: random.randrange(10)
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            text: root.r1c1
        Button:
            text: root.r1c2
""")

class Highest(Screen):
    pass


# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Highest(name='Highest'))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

My code works if I just have one button with text - *Hello*. Random seems not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's because `randrange` isn't returning a string, but an int. You could try:

```
r1c2: str(random.randrange(10))
```

OR

Try adding it as a function to your root widget:

```
class Highest(Screen):

    def get_rand(self):
        return str(random.randrange(10))
```

And your kv would look like this:

```
r1c2: root.get_rand()
```

Comment: giving error, random is not defined. is it working at your end?

Comment: I figured out an alternative, by using choice instead of random.randrange and it worked. Thanks

Comment: looks like In you code you had imported random incorrectly. to call random.randrange for instance, you would only need to have 'import random' up top. Instead you have 'from random import random' written twice. Same with choice. To call random.choice, the import you need is 'import random'.